# when does bz2.decompress(rawdata) got an error of "couldn't find end of stream"?

Tags: python, scipy, compression

I have checked that the file in my disk is the same as https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/misc/face.dat

### but when I run this statement ,I have got this error. why ?

```
scipy.misc.face()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\common.py", line 567, in face
data = bz2.decompress(rawdata)
ValueError: couldn't find end of stream
```

Comment: How did you read in rawdata? That `face.dat` decodes from the commandline (on Linux). Did you open the file with `'rb'`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug (on Windows), see here

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/7f0210fd28a2b3be79806d5cae462be52c1601e9